# How to Animate seperate Views in sequence one by one

Tags: react-native, animation, react-native-reanimated

- Im begginer in React-native-reanimated,
- I try to understand what is the structure to render View elements one after one.
- i can do it with declare and wrap each item in animation with delay but is the worst way that i can think about it.

so what I want to do, for example is to show the DrawerItems one by one, when any item opacity  reaches to 0.5 start the next animate drawer item and so on.

my drawer component now:

```
const DrawerContent = ({ progress, ...rest }) => {
const navigate = rest.navigation.navigate;
const translateX = Animated.interpolate(progress, {
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [-300, 0],
});

return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "white" }}>
        <DrawerContentScrollView {...rest}>
            <DrawerItemList {...rest} />
            <View>
                <Text>dsadsa</Text>
                <Animated.View style={{ transform: [{ translateX }] }}>
                    <DrawerItem
                        icon={({ color, size }) => <Icon name="facebook" color={color} size={size} />}
                        label="ראשי"
                        onPress={() => navigate("Main")}
                    />
                </Animated.View>
                <DrawerItem
                    icon={({ color, size }) => <Icon name="facebook" color={color} size={size} />}
                    label="קבע תור"
                    onPress={() => navigate("MeetingPicker")}
                />
                <DrawerItem
                    icon={({ color, size }) => <Icon name="facebook" color={color} size={size} />}
                    label="התורים שלי"
                    onPress={() => navigate("MyMeetings")}
                />
                <DrawerItem
                    icon={({ color, size }) => <Icon name="facebook" color={color} size={size} />}
                    label="מי אני"
                    onPress={() => navigate("About")}
                />
                <DrawerItem
                    icon={({ color, size }) => <Icon name="facebook" color={color} size={size} />}
                    label="גלריה"
                    onPress={() => navigate("Gallery")}
                />
                <DrawerItem
                    icon={({ color, size }) => <Icon name="facebook" color={color} size={size} />}
                    label="מיקום"
                    onPress={() => navigate("Location")}
                />
                <DrawerItem
                    icon={({ color, size }) => <Icon name="facebook" color={color} size={size} />}
                    label="התנתק"
                    onPress={() => navigate("Logout")}
                />
            </View>
        </DrawerContentScrollView>
        <View></View>
        <Text>sign out a//</Text>
    </View>
    );
}; 
const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
export default DrawerContent;
```

- the explanation dont must be for this example, you can explain me how to exec animation in a sequence of views